# Using flask url_for in script tag to pass parameters to a route

Tags: javascript, flask

I want to pass a token to a route from my script tag but cant find a way to make this work.

So far I have made this:

```
<script>
some code...
  window.location.href = {{ url_for ("payment_success", token=token ) }};
</script>
```

But it's not returning anything. All my routes are ok. I don't have really much idea about javascript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devil hides in details. I forgot to put "" between `{{ url_for..... }}`